# Java Swing: Button's specific id. How can I catch pressed button in listener not using .getActionCommand?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, listeners

I have to write an ActionListener to JPanel.

The task, depending on the button pressed to cause the required action. The only way that I know - to get the label from the button using `event.getActionCommand()` and depending on that string to cause the desired action.

But I think that to have a binding to the label is wrong way, very wrong way. 
Are there other options?

In other words my question is: How can I determinate pressed button?

Comment: You'll likely get 100 different answers for this, but as for me, I've been favoring use of anonymous inner classes for my listeners that then call control methods.

Comment: To amplify, I also use enums and Maps with a command design pattern to allow the control to know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swing is an *event driven architecture*. So whenever you're trying to perform any type of interaction with a component, you would ideally be capturing or working with the corresponding event associated with the component.

What you would need to do is add an *ActionListener*, and when an action is performed (*pressing of the button in this case*), you would be calling the method (*the "required action"*) you were talking about in your code. If you're new to ActionListener, you might find: ["How to Write an Action Listener"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) to be helpful

Answer (score 2):

One thing I've done is something like this:

```
// Action Listener method
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // Did somebody push my button?
    if (e.getSource() == myButton) {
        myCaller.doButton(myButton, myValue);
    }
}
```